# Replace char* in function without memory leak

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to make a find-and-replace function, and it works, but valgrind reports huge memory leaks.

Have a look:

```
void repl(char** str) {

    // build a new string (simulating find&replace)

    char* replacement = (char*)malloc(7);
    strcpy(replacement, "my ass");

    // this causes "free(): invalid pointer" crash
    //free(*str);

    *str = replacement; // return to caller
}

/* main function */
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    // out original string
    char* str = "memory leak here";
    repl(&str); // replace something 1st time
    repl(&str); // 2nd time
    repl(&str); // 3rd time

    printf("%s\n",str); // look at output

    exit(0);
}
```

When the "free" is in place, you will get:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./test: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000401013 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7f264e7ecb96]
....
```

If the `free` is not there, however, you get a memory leak (valgrind output):

```
==26236== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26236==    definitely lost: 14 bytes in 2 blocks
==26236==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26236==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26236==    still reachable: 7 bytes in 1 blocks
==26236==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I'm not entirely familiar with pointers yet, so please have some patience.
Perhaps this is not the best way, so please suggest better method for find-and-replace with no memory leaks.

I tried just returning the result, but then I got leaks as well.

Comment: +1 Good question, and it shows you're trying to solve it yourself.

Comment: Are you hoping for a function that will smartly *not* delete a non-allocated string (such as your first-case const string) *and* correctly free a *dynamic* string allocated with a prior call? I only ask because if that is the intent, the *problem* isn't a function that does it. The problem is expecting a function to do it for you in the first place. (and nice that you used valgrind on this; you're already ahead of most people new to C and pointers).

Comment: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51010-dynamic-arrays-using-malloc-and-realloc/ Check this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WHAT'S UP WITH `glibc`?**

The `glibc` diagnostic is related to the fact that `str` doesn't always point to a memory segment allocated by `malloc`, which is one of the requirements of `free`. In other words; your first call to `repl` with the value of `str` pointing to a non-malloced memory segment will cause `free` to misbehave.

---

**WHAT'S UP WITH `valgrind`?**

The valgrind diagnostics are there because of the fact that without your (currently malfunctioning) usage of `free`, the memory allocated by `malloc` inside `repl` is never released, and hence; you are leaking memory.

---

**PROPOSED SOLUTION**

I feel like it's better to explain it in words instead of handing you a functioning implementation, since you seems to be eager to learn by doing.

1. don't accept a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char*, instead accept a `pointer-to-char` and return a pointer to a new memory segment that consists of a modified version of the string passed in. This new memory segment has been allocated through `malloc`,
2. rename your function to make it clear that it is allocating memory that needs to be released,
3. document your function so that the caller knows that it is responsible for `free`ing the memory, not your *replace-function*.

Comment: I see. So how do I check whether the incoming string is malloc'd?

Comment: @MightyPork: You can't and you don't want to anyway.

Comment: right, so any suggestions how to solve my problem? Now I see what's wrong, but no way to fix it.

Comment: @MightyPork: I suggested how to solve it in my answer. You have to make an assumption; either you assume that you need to free the buffer (like `realloc` does) or you do not and you force the caller to manage their own memory (better option).

Comment: @MightyPork see the section marked "proposed solution"

Comment: good solution.. Gives some extra effort to caller, but it works when done right.

Comment: How in the world you are going to decide if a pointer after the replacement is to be freed??? You aren't going to make the caller responsible for it, will you? Can you imagine the ugly mess of code it is going to require???

Comment: @MightyPork No, it's an awful solution! Do a small prototype to see how putting the caller on the hook for freeing the memory makes your code look like an ugly mess in zero time.

Comment: for(int i=0; i<100; i++){ old=str; str=repl(old); if(i>0) free(old); }  --- actually, not looking that bad, when used in a loop.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If you'd like to accept pointers to any kind of allocated storage, this is the way to do it (ie. having a function which is not dependent on where the segment is coming from). OP could create a different function which has *built-in* `free` functionality, which is basically a wrapper around the proposed function solution.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp That's the thing, you never want to accept a pointer to any kind of memory **and** be allowed to resize it at the same time.  It never works - the API that you get becomes fragile, waiting to cause a memory leak at any time. If you want a resize, it needs to be in the heap, and you need to own it.

Answer (score 3):

you can't delete/free the "memory leak here" string cause its not actually there for you to free, its a constant character sequence inside the program code, thats why you get runtime error for invalid pointer. When you removed free, the 14 bytes lost is cause you allocated 7 bytes three times, but only the last one you can refer to.

Answer (score 2):

You `free` what you `malloc`, that is all. Calling `free` on memory that was not allocated by `malloc` or `realloc` invokes undefined behavior. That is why your first call to `free` results in an error; what `str` points to was not allocated dynamically.

It seems like a poor design as well.  The function takes a buffer as its input.  It should not be making assumptions about this buffer other than that it is valid to write to.  It should not be calling `free` on its input; it's the caller's job to make sure memory is cleaned up.

In that same vein, you don't even need the `malloc`.  You could just write to the buffer directly and force the user to allocate it (this is more canonical.) In the case that you need to return dynamically allocated memory you should document that the returned memory must be freed by the caller. Your model must be consistent about ownership.

Comment: The problem is that I don't in advance know how long the buffer will have to be. However, based on your first suggestion (leave `free` to caller), I think I got it working. Still needs some further testing though. (then again, the caller assumes the returned string is malloc'd, poor design again, eh?

Comment: @MightyPork: Well, if the returned string can be any size it's probably not achievable without returning a dynamically allocated string.  That's ok, there are C library functions which do the same thing. As long as it is documented that the caller assumes ownership of the memory that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem of ownership of the string that you pass into the `repl` function: as soon as you do this

```
*str = replacement;
```

the memory pointed to by the `*str` is gone forever, becoming a memory leak. That is why you need to free it before reassignment.

But this is not the end of it! It implies that you cannot pass a string constant or an array of `char` allocated in static or automatic storage to your `repl`, because that cannot be freed. Hence, you need to make a copy of the original before passing it to `repl`:

```
void repl(char** str) {
    char* replacement = malloc(7);
    strcpy(replacement, "my ass");
    // This will no longer be a problem - see the change in main()
    free(*str);
    *str = replacement; // return to caller
}

/* main function */
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    // Now that the original string is malloced,
    // free() inside repl() is no longer a problem:
    char* str = malloc(17);
    strcpy(str, "memory leak here");
    repl(&str); // replace something 1st time
    repl(&str); // 2nd time
    repl(&str); // 3rd time
    printf("%s\n",str); // look at output
    exit(0);
}
```

Note that in the actual `repl` you may be better off using realloc - it has a potential of speeding things up for small replacements.

Comment: ok, but isn't it a bad idea to _require_ the input string to be alloc'd, without having a way to verify it?

Comment: **-1**: @MightyPork yes, it's a bad idea and isn't normally recommended practice.

Comment: @MightyPork Unfortunately, you have no other way to go about doing it: there is absolutely, positively, no way to find if a pointer is from a heap, the stack, or from the static storage without resorting to some sort of a hack. The caller cannot possibly be made responsible for freeing that memory either, because he has no idea if the `free()` is going to be required or not.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp Not only it isn't a bad idea, that's also the only way to go. Note: downvoting a competing answer is an awfully bad form.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not downvoting a competeing answer because it's a competing answer, I was downvoting it because I found the answer to be misleading/incorrect. It's not the only way to go, but I see now that the OPs question doesn't involve any pre-requirements of the pointer passed to the funciton, and usage of the function.. with that I will remove the former *un-downvote*.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp What specifically did you find "misleading/incorrect" about the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Free is added in the caller

```
/* main function */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    // out original string
    char* str = "memory leak here";
    repl(&str); // replace something 1st time
    free(str);
    repl(&str); // 2nd time
    free(str);
    repl(&str); // 3rd time

    printf("%s\n",str); // look at output
    free(str);
    exit(0);
}
```